# PHP preg_match returning character count of string instead of expected result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to search for variables being defined in a shell script.

```
<?php
$code = '
#!/bin/bash
foo = "Hello world!"
bar="123"
echo -e "The value of foo is $foo\n"
echo -e "The value of bar is $bar"
';
$var_pattern = "/(^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[\= ]+([\"\']?)+(.)+([\"\']?))*$/";
preg_match($var_pattern, $code, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

There are two variables being defined in the above example (foo & bar). The regex I have checked using regex101.com.

The result I am getting is...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 121
        )

)
```

121 appears to be the number of chars within the code. The result I am expecting is something more like...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => foo = "Hello world!"
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] => bar="123"
        )
)
```

Or similar! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's what `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` does. It includes the match position. Aren't you looking for `preg_match_all`?

Comment: @mario I tried preg_match_all and got similar results (i.e. character count) from that too

Comment: First off you need to add the m flag to your pattern or else ^ and $ match the start and end of the string instead of the newlines inside it.

Comment: Check your regex, maybe this works better for your purposes: /^\b\w+\s*[\=]\s*([\"\']).*\1/

Comment: @mario Maybe you show example with explanation?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original approach had a couple of woes:

- Was missing the `/m` multiline flag, so `^$` didn't anchor lines.
- The outer `(…)*` capture group was completely optionalized `*`
- While `(.)+` would capture just one letter of the contained value.
- And `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` is redundant unless you actually want match positions.

Since this is more or less a classic ini-style format, you can simply use:

```
                     key                  value        multiline
                      ↑                     ↑             ↑
 preg_match_all("/^ (\w+) \s*=\s* [\"\']? (.+?) [\"\']? $/mix", $str, $m);
                             ↓       ↓             ↓
                           equal   quote         quote
```

And after that you can even reconstruct an associative key→value array from the `$m` matches array, with [`=array_combine($m[1], $m[2])`](http://php.net/array_combine).

Comment: after all these years I thought I had almost, finally got my head around regex. You have proved that theory to be wrong :( However, your revised regex works (as tested so far) and your explanation is very useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following pattern:

```
/([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\s*=\s*(|['"])(.+)\2/g
```

Working example @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hB3fZ6/1)